# How do I find the program process id number to kill program automatically in assembly on Linux?

Tags: linux, assembly, process, x86-64, kill

With this, I can find the process id number of the program:

```
ps -auwx | grep vlc | awk '{print$2}' | head -n 1
```

In an assembly program, how do I find the process id dynamically?

```
section .text
global _start
_start:
      mov rax,62 ; syscall for kill
      mov rdi,5265 ; pid of vlc media player
      mov rsi,9 ;signal
      syscall
      mov rax,60
      mov rdi,0
      syscall
```

Comment: normally in the shell you'd use `pgrep vlc` to find a PID, or `pkill vlc` to kill processes that match.  `pgrep` is like `ps`|`grep` but somewhat more efficient, and it knows to ignore itself.

Comment: Why would you want to do this in assembly language?

Comment: Thank u very much @PeterCordes i'm trying  pkill vlc using execve in assembly.

Comment: @lurker i'm learning shell coding & system calls on linux.So, that i can become a hacker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tedious to do.  What you need to do is walk through the `/proc` file system, reading the `cmdline` files for each process to determine which process is the one you are interested in.  You might also need to implement some sort of string matching procedure so you can match `/usr/bin/vlc` as well as `vlc`.

See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for documentation.

Comment: Or check inode numbers from `stat(2)` (which follows symlinks) on `/proc/PID/exe` to see if it's the same fs:inode as `/usr/bin/vlc`.  That's not the same check, of course, because it won't match a process started from a `/usr/bin/vlc` that's since been replaced.

Comment: @PeterCordes You should not rely on just the inode.  The combination of inode number and file system id is a unique key identifying a file on the system.  As long as the process is running, the inode of its image is not reused, so relying on this is safe.  What is not safe is following the symlink blindly.  If the file was unlinked, the symlink has a special value identifying the combination of file system and inode specifying what the file was.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I said about it not being the same check as matching on the string in `cmdline`.  Unlinking the original does *not* change the inode you see with `stat`.  It's not "special", it's still the original value which can't be recycled until the inode has no references (open file descriptors or mappings).  I did `cp -a /bin/sleep /tmp`, ran that sleep, then `rm`ed it.  I was still able to `cat /proc/PID/exe | less` to access the contents and everything.  According to `stat(1)`, the file still has a link count of `1`, which is odd.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's not what I meant.  My point was that two process images could have the same inode number but on different file systems.  To make sure that you distinguish these two, you also need to check if the file system id matches.

Comment: Oh, sorry, now I see that's what you were trying to say.  I did write "fs:inode" once in my first comment, but I see now that I didn't ever state that very clearly.  And good point about the symlinks to deleted files in `/proc/` being special, so you can't just follow symlinks; you need to parse a readlink result if `stat` fails.